# Object Oriented With Azure

Tags: angular, azure

I have an object

```
export class Programme
{
id: string;
title: string;
organizer: Organizer;
participants: Participant[];
}
```

When i uploading the object on the azure tables
It is storing like this

```
{
    "id": "ef67998c-27f5-4c2a-8c80-b29d822d2eef",
    "title": "Python",
    "organizer": "[object Object]",
    "participants": "[object Object]"
}
```

Adding to the table:

```
var table = this.client.getTable("programme");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            table.insert(prog)
                .then(function (modules) {
                    resolve(modules)
                }, function (error) { reject(error) });
        });
```

How can i avoid this?

Comment: Can you share your code for uploading to table? I'm guessing that you would need to serialize the object before saving to table.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks. Have updated question with code. So for every property, i need to do that? Could I do something on nodeJS backend, that I don't have make frontend so messy?

Comment: This is not for Azure Storage tables. Am I correct? I think you would need to only serialize object type properties.

Comment: It is Easy Tables that comes along app service.

Comment: I meant if i need serialise `organizer` and `participants` for this case, right? When i add new i need to do again and again! :(

Comment: I haven't used easy tables but my guess is that you're right.